# How to monitor the data addition of a specified DolphinDB table in Python?

Tags: streaming, dolphindb

For example, when a trading tool automatically issues an order, related information will be written into a DolphinDB table named table1. I want to develop an independent risk control tool that can read the new data written into table1, access the associated risk, and trigger an alarm if the data surpasses predefined thresholds.

Answer (score 0):

Stream computing can be used for real-time data monitoring. If related trading information is written into a message-oriented middleware, you can use scripts in combination with plugins to trigger an alarm; if the information is processed through Python API, you can subscribe to a stream table in API and define the handler function to achieve callback logic.